# Clasp fail while running

Tags: google-apps-script, clasp

I am using the clasp to run AppScript

Example:

```
clasp run myFunction dev
```

but its showing error here like

> Requested entity was not found

please let me know why it's happening?

Comment: https://github.com/google/clasp/blob/master/README.md#run

Answer (score 0):

You need to deploy the script as "API Executable". Then add sufficient authorization scopes to call the function.

Comment: @tehhowch Since it's clasp, I don't think the same project requirement applies. However, OP needs to copy ``project ID`` to ``.clasp.json``, I think.

Comment: That's the Cloud Platform project requirement ;)